# Grouping of characters inside the square bracket instead Like or Like

Tags: sql-server

How can I summarize this code?

```
...
where
code LIKE 'TTAD%'
or
code LIKE 'TTAG%'
or
code LIKE 'TTAW%'
or
code LIKE 'TTE%'
or
code LIKE 'TTK%'
```

I write this:

```
...
where
Code LIKE 'TT[AD,AG,AW,E,K]%'
```

but, I don't want this code returns, for example, 'TTAK' or 'TTEK'.

Answer (score 3):

SQL Server does not natively support regex, so the best we can probably do using the enhanced `LIKE` operator is:

```sql
WHERE code LIKE 'TTA[DGW]%' OR code LIKE 'TT[EK]%'
```

Note that the above does in fact match `TTEK`.  If you want to exclude that, you use:

```sql
WHERE (code LIKE 'TTA[DGW]%' OR code LIKE 'TT[EK]%') AND   -- whitelist
      code NOT LIKE 'TTEK%'   -- blacklist
```